# AWS cognito AUTHORIZATION Endpoint returns bad request (400)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I like to use the [Authorization-endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) endpoint of user pool to authenticate with facebook.

[Authorization-endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) of aws incognito for a federated Facebook identity pool of a user pool returns status 400 bad request. No more details in the payload of error, just some HTML. How can i get more detailed information on whats going wrong?

Usage:

```
curl 'https://<mydomain>.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorizer?response_type=code&client_id=<myAppClientId>&redirect_uri=https://<customdomain>.com&state=profile+aws.cognito.signin.user.admin&identity_provider=Facebook'
```

Configuration of AppClient:
[image]

Comment: You should check error message.
If you are getting `redirect_mismatch` , this means that the redirect url is different from defined in configuration.

Comment: @EdgardLeal, there is no error message provided in response html: `<p align="center">An error was encountered with the requested page.</p>
                        <br>
                        <p align="center">
                            <a href="#" onclick="displayErrorMessage();">View error</a>
                        </p>
                        <div id="errorMsg" align="center" class="hidden">`

Comment: found it. the url endpoint was `/oauth2/authorizer` instead of `oauth2/authorize`. @EdgardLeal, thank you very mutch for listen to me ;) !